# How to update (append to) an multiple href in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

The below code is working fine. Any one help me the same scenario for 
http://jsbin.com/axohar/3

```
 $(function(){
  $('input:checkbox').click(function(){
    var id  = this.id; // No need for `attr`

    if(this.checked){  // No need for `attr`
        $("<div>")
            .text($(this.parentNode).text())
            .attr("data-contents", id)
            .appendTo("#members");
    }
    else {
        $('div[data-contents="' + id + '"]').remove();
    }
});

});
```

Instead of label i need hyperlink (html). The reason is i want to list out all the fields with hyperlink at run time.

```
<a href="tag_a.asp">The a tag1</a>
<a href="tag_a.asp">The a tag1</a>

example
link1
link2
link3
```

Comment: Sorry, but your problem is unclear.

Comment: I want to create multiple anchor element based on my list of field at run time 
For example: 
http://jsbin.com/axohar/3
Instead of div tag , i want to show anchor tag.

Comment: you want links instead of text on checkbox check?

Comment: yes, you are correct. Ehsan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `html()` and can append anchor tag in div this way:

```
$("<div>")
.html('<a href="http://www.google.com">'+$(this.parentNode).text()+'</a>')
.attr("data-contents", id)
.appendTo("#members");
```